# 10BASE-T Layout Guidelines

Tags: ethernet, layout, differential, trace

How critical are parameters like trace length matching, differential impedance, vias, etc. when designing a 10BASE-T only application? I know that due to the reduced frequency, there is a larger margin for error than for higher data rates, but there must be good-practice maximums and minimums.

For example, in a two-layer PCB that I am designing, I have the following parameters:

- TX+ length: 25.946mm
- TX- length: 26.764mm
- RX+ length: 26.420mm
- RX- length: 27.769mm
- Differential impedance: 123ohm
- Odd impedance: 61.7ohm

The 8P8C connector has integrated magnetics and the MAC/PHY is the ENC28J60. Sorry about the messy labels.

[image: Sample 10BASE-T layout]

Comment: That'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

10 Base-T runs at 10MHz, usually you don't need to worry about transmission line effects and impedance matching until 50MHz. It would be slightly better to keep traces short, and a ground plane underneath them if you can, this design looks ok.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a ground plane, but it's not shown in the picture.